# SQL FILESTREAM and Connection Pooling

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlfilestream

I am currently enhancing a product to support web delivery of large file-content.
I would like to store it in the database, and whether or not I choose to FILESTREAM by BLOB, the following question still holds.

My WCF method will return a stream, meaning that the file stream will remain open while the content is read by the client. If the connection is slow, then the stream could be open for some time.

**Question**: Connection pooling assumes that connections are exclusively held, only for a short period of time. Am I correct in assuming, that given I have a connection pool of finite size, there could be a contention problem, if slow network connections are used to download files?

Under this assumption, I really want to use FILESTREAM, and open the file directly from the file-system, rather than the SQL connection. However, if the database is remote, I will have no choice but to pull the content from the SQL connection (until I have a local cache of the file anyway).

I realise I have other options, such as to server-buffer the stream, however that will have implications as well. I wish at this time, to discuss only the issues relating to returning a stream obtained from a DB connection.